# Application Insights Analytics Data Color

Tags: azure-application-insights

Is it possible to ***change the color*** on the rendered dots in a scatter chart in Application Insights Analytics?

I'm looking into some data and Analytics apparently thinks that light blue and light green is the best way of rendering this and I don't. Better contrast between the colors would be beneficial.

**Image of the chart**

[image: Chart displaying data nodes with light blue and light green color.]

Answer (score 1):

We can't customize that.

you can vote for it here:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-application-insights/suggestions/33660235-set-color-legend